# Amazon tablets disconnect from WiFi intermittently - how to debug?

Tags: wifi-configuration

My home network runs through an Asus RT-N66U, with Updated firmware.  Various devices connect through it (iPhones, iPads, android, PCs, Macs, printers, etc), via both wired and WiFi connections.  Everything works fine, except for amazon tablets.  Alexa dots work fine, but I’ve owned at least three Fire tablets, and they’ve all had the same problem: intermittently (multiple times per day, usually multiple times per hour), they show that they are connected to WiFi, but in fact they have lost connection.  I have to turn WiFi off and in again to force them to reconnect.

I’m not sure what the root of the issue is.  I’ve tried assigning static IPs, but that didn’t help.  Any suggestions for tracking down the issue?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the log files. Setup a machine with 'Syslog Watcher' https://syslogwatcher.com/ and configure port 514 UDP through the machine firewall. Somewhere in the firmware you use find the syslog / logging section and look for somewhere that mentions external syslog or external destination. Type in the IP address of the syslog server machine. Capture logs. All or Debug should be selected as the logging level on the router.

This is an extremely cut down version of the full instructions, but give this a go.

Changing the encryption method from WPA/WPA2 mixed or WPA2 to WPA would also help, but will lower the overall security of your network and you won't learn anything about system logs.